# ¿Por qué el form con el método post en html para ejecutar un php no funciona? Aparece el error 405

Tags: php, html

*Ahora mismo esta página no está disponible

Si el problema continúa, póngase en contacto con el propietario del sitio.
HTTP ERROR 405*

Mi código
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lectura recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos.

Comment: gracias, pero necesito ayuda :"( no se por qué no me sale :"(

Comment: El error 405 es un problema en el método en tu caso el `post`. El recurso existe (tu página "Actividad10.php") y el servidor entiende lo que estas pidiendo, pero no para ese método. A mi me parece un problema del servidor web, cual estas usando?

Comment: 1. El código siempre _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. 2. Buscá _error 405 HTTP_... ¿Está implementado el método POST en tu código?

Comment: Dentro del link, punto 2: ***Tiene código completo en texto (sin pantallazos del código).*** Esto hace más fácil que cualquier usuario pueda copiar/pegar el código que tienes, reproduzca tu escenario y con ello aumentas las chances de obtener respuesta(s). Saludos.

Comment: Primero, pon código en texto. Lo mas probable es que no estas en un servidor WEB. Porque cualquiera (como XAMPP) te exige trabajar en localhost no en la IP. Pueda que por ahí esté el problema, que servidor estas usando?